# excel vba userforms: user-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, automation, userform, vba

My Excel book contains a user form called `myUserForm`. 
I want to open it, fill it with data and programmatically press its buttons, but

```
Sub myUserFormShow()
 Dim muf As myUserForm
 muf.Show
End Sub
```

prompts an error `User-defined type not defined`. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Why press the button programmatically? Will the user not click on the button? Please explain in detail as to what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Sub myUserFormShow()
 myUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you know why http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155729(v=office.10).aspx does not work in my case?

Comment: Have no even slightest idea buddy. Being QA I'd ask for: "please provide more details relevant to the issue")

Comment: Do you know how to clck buttons programmatically? myUserForm.myButton1.Run and myUserForm.myButton1.Click do not compile.

Comment: @YuccaV I think this may help: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/22555-can-visual-basic-applications-%22click%22-button.html